# Calculate discount using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, keyup

I am calculating Discount using jquery. But I have a problem calculating the correct discount. My calculation gives me wrong result.

Here is my code

```js
$(document).on("change keyup blur", "#chDiscount", function() {
  var amd = $('#cBalance').val();
  var disc = $('#chDiscount').val();
  if (disc != '' && amd != '')
    $('#cBalance').val((parseInt(amd)) - (parseInt(disc)));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" id="cBalance" value="1575">
<br>
<input type="number" id="chDiscount">
```

I have a prepopulated value for `cBalance` input i.e.,`1575`. When I type discount value for example 500 in `chDiscount` input, it gives me `1020` and not 1075. And I want the value `1575` to be `1575` when there is no value or zero value in the `chDiscount` input. And the caculation keeps incrementing the cBalance value whenever I type new value in the chDiscount input, it does not increment from the default value. 
My exptected output: When I type 500, I want the default value 1575 to be 1075. And if I delete the 1000 that I type, I want back the default value 1575 in cBalance. And If I type 5 in chDiscount, the default value would become 1570 and if I hit backspace to delete, it would become 1575 again.
How can I achieve this? Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Comment: well logicly, because it first gets 5 then 50 then 500 and you're left with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("change keyup blur", "#chDiscount", function() {
  var amd = $('#cBalance').val();
  var disc = $('#chDiscount').val();
  if (disc != '' && amd != '') {
    $('#result').val((parseInt(amd)) - (parseInt(disc)));
  }else{
    $('#result').val(parseInt(amd));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" id="cBalance" value="1575">
<br>
<input type="number" id="chDiscount">
<br>
<input type="number" id="result">
```

I added result field because otherwise you couldn't specify amd

Comment: Almost correct. When there is no data in the second input.  it leaves me with 1570.

Comment: It's correct just doesn't refresh, let me take care of that too :)

Comment: In your snippet, If I type 500, it gives me correct result. But If I press backspace and left with no value, i.e, just blank. it leaves me with 1570 and not 1575. If you can fix it, I would be grateful.

Comment: I don't want a third input. Please help.

Comment: could you then monitor for only eneter key, not every keyup ?

Comment: OK, thanks, I did it using only enter key. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nothing ;) I'm glad to help

Answer (score 1):

As above mention code is just subtracting the main value. here is exact solution

```
<input type="number" id="cBalance" value="1575"> <br>
   <input type="number" id="chDiscount"> <br>
   <input type="number" id="result">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).on("change keyup blur", "#chDiscount", function() {
  var main = $('#cBalance').val();
  var disc = $('#chDiscount').val();
  var dec = (disc/100).toFixed(2); //its convert 10 into 0.10
 var mult = main*dec; // gives the value for subtract from main value
 var discont = main-mult;
  $('#result').val(discont);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/siddhuphp/4sob8ov1/)